# Send an SMS from mobile connected to a PC and persist the incoming messages

Tags: java, php, mysql, mobile, sms

I want to send an SMS from a mobile phone which is connected to a PC. This sending process should be accessed using a browser (should be a web based application). Moreover, incoming messages should be persisted in a MySQL database. Is this possible? Any ideas may help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether there's any kind of API for the mobile. If not, get another mobile. If you post the exact product name someone may point you in the right direction.

Al other requirements are easily handled with any web application. Dive into servlet/JSP or PHP programming.